# C++ : Ignoring multiple << Operators in a line

Tags: c++, logging, stream, operator-keyword

Say I have the following code:

```
int ignored = 0;
StreamIgnore si;

si << "This part" << " should be" << ignored << std::endl;
```

I want that when this code runs `si` will simply ignore the rest of the stream.
The thing is I want this to be as efficient as possible.
One obvious solution would be to have:

```
template <typename T>
StreamIgnore& opertaor<<(const T& val) {
    //Do nothing
    return *this;
}
```

BUT, if the code was something like:

```
StreamIgnore si;

si << "Fibonacci(100) = " << fib(100) << std::endl;
```

Then I'll have to calculate `fib(100)` before the `//Do Nothing` part.
So, I want to be able to ignore the rest completely without any unnecessary computations.

To make this request make sense, think that `StreamIgnore` could be a `StreamIgnoreOrNot` class, and the c'tor decides whether to ignore the stream or not by either returning `*this` and use the stream, or a `new StreamIgnore()` instance and ignoring the rest.

I thought about using Macros some how but could't come up with something that enables me to use this syntax (i.e `"si << X << Y..."`).

I would appreciate it if someone could suggest a way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: it likely (if `fib` has no side effects) that the compiler will remove the `fib(100)` for you. You can make something similar to what you want that is guaranteed to be completely removed but the code involved heavy templates ( you can do something like :`si << prop_callback(fib)(100);`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'd obviously use IOstreams with disabling/enabling the output amounting to setting/clearing `std::ios_base::failbit`. Doing this will readily prevent formatting and writing the data. It won't prevent evaluation of arguments, though. For that purpose I'd use the logical and operator:

```
si && si << not_evaluated() << when_not_used();
```

Comment: Note this will only work when it's the default `&&` operator that's being used.  If you overload the `&&` operator, it is no longer short-circuiting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I liked the use of && to prevent the rest. This would be perfect for me since I was going to use an `if` anyway, so this doesn't add any branching to the code.
Could you elaborate on the failbit some more, I didn't quite get what I need it for?

Comment: @ShaZiv: setting `std::ios_base::failbit` puts the stream into a mode where it won't do anything. Also, it causes the stream to convert to `false` rather than to `true` in boolean contexts like the logical and operator.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thank you very much, you've saved me valuable time!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this (without cheating, as you will see below). Your code is only passed the result of `fib(100)` and as such cannot short-circuit execution here at all.

However, there is a simple hack you can use:

```
template<typename T> struct is_ignored { static const bool yes = false; };
template<> struct is_ignored<StreamIgnore> { static const bool yes = true; };

#define S(x) if(!is_ignored<remove_reference<decltype(x)>::type>::yes) x
S(x) << "meep\n";
```

You may have to add some `_Pragma`s to disable compiler warnings about the fact that this leads to dead code.